# Unable to connect to TLS channel of WMQ server v7.0.1.14

Tags: ssl, websphere, ibm-mq, tls1.2

My web application is hosted in Websphere Application Server. For all outgoing connection, we have dynamic SSL outbounds configured at server level.Currently, due to patching, SSLv3 has been disabled. Now even though we have upgraded the SSL outbound to support TLSV1.2, and use a TLS based channel MQ channel, still connection to WMQ is failing. The details are provided below. Can someone please help out here?

Websphere Server Details :

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6460sr16fp60-20180213_02(SR16 FP60))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Linux amd64-64 jvmxa6460sr16fp60-20180125_377078 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20180125_377078      
JIT  - r9_20180125_377078
GA24_Java6_SR16_20180125_1132_B377078)      
java version "1.6.0"
JCL  - 20180209_01

Websphere MQ version : 7.0.1.14
MQ client jar(com.ibm.mq.jar) version : 5.304 - j5304-G030613.1
Application Code is compiled using JDK 1.6_U80
```

The error logs are :

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2400' ('MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE').
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:223)
                ... 50 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2400;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'gbrdsr000000542.intranet.barcapint.com(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2400;AMQ9231: The supplied parameter is not valid. [1=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]],3=gbrdsr000000542.intranet.barcapint.com(1414),5=RemoteTCPConnection.chooseSocketFactory]
                at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2177)
                at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1308)
                at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:373)
                ... 49 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2400;AMQ9231: The supplied parameter is not valid. [1=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
                at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection.chooseSocketFactory(RemoteTCPConnection.java:2122)
                at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection.makeSocketSecure(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1933)
                at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection.connnectUsingLocalAddress(RemoteTCPConnection.java:753)
                at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1164)
                at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:1306)
                at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnectionPool.getConnection(RemoteConnectionPool.java:372)
                at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1734)
                ... 51 more
```

The MQ side details :

```
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(MQ.TLS.BFH.CHL)                 CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
   ALTDATE(2017-11-07)                     ALTTIME(08.35.01)
   COMPHDR(NONE)                           COMPMSG(NONE)
   DESCR(Client channel for BFH WAS Client)
   SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
   SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256)
            TRPTYPE(TCP)
```

The cipher suite being used in JAVA - `SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`

Comment: What version of WAS is running?

Comment: Hi Josh..The version of the WAS server is : 7.0.0.43. Service refresh - 16.

Comment: 7.0.1.14 MQ client should be able to support SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256.  I think the problem is that you reference this: `MQ client jar(com.ibm.mq.jar) version : 5.304 - j5304-G030613.1`.  WAS should come with all of the required jars as part of the MQ RA (Resource Adapter) that is included.  I would recommend you remove the above `com.ibm.mq.jar` and any other `com.ibm.mq*` jars that you have added.

Comment: If this is the cause I'll write it up in more detail in an answer.

Comment: Hi Josh..thanks for responding..so what you are recommending is to remove the com.ibm.mq.jar of version 5.304 and replace it with 7.0.1.14 MQ client jar, for my client java application?

Comment: No what I'm saying is that WAS 7.0.0.43 comes with the IBM MQ v7.0.1.14 RA (Resource Adapter) which basically encompasses all the jar files that a app running outside of WAS would use.

Comment: Also note that WebSphere Application Server V7.0 went out of support on April 30, 2018.

Comment: Note that MQv5.3 where that jar you have came from has been out of support since September 28 2007.

Comment: Yeah..its literally a legacy application I am working on. I am extremely sorry if I am being naive, but I have to ask you - the 5.3 client jar that I am using, is used to import the MQQueueConnectionFactory class of IBM MQ client in my code. If I remove it from my application dependency, the application code will not compile. I will have to replace it with some IBM MQ jar, to resolve the dependency/import the MQQueueConnectionFactory class. What should that be then?

Comment: Is the 5.3 jar deployed with the application?  If so try just deploying it after compile without the 5.3 jar.  It should work in was.  7.0 is also out of support from MQ side since September 30 2015, as part of the bundle with WAS 7.0 it would have continued to be supported until it went out of support at the end of April.  You can probably still download 7.0.1.14 client app and the jar files will be included with that.

Comment: I will try both the approaches - with 7.0.1.14 client app and removing 5.3 client jar. Will update here accordingly. Thanks for the suggestions John. Cheers!

Comment: Hi John..I could not get my hands on 7.0.1.14 MQ client jars, however I tried with 6.0.1.1 version jar, and still getting the same error. Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2400;AMQ9231: The supplied parameter is not valid. [1=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]. Is there a possibility that the IBM JRE 1.6.0 SR16 is not supporting the TLS cipher? I can see the JNDIs using TLS are working fine. But when I configure the MQQueueConnectionFactory in java, with this TLS cipher spec..it is throwing error? How can I verify, if this is the case?

Comment: I think you are addressing this to me (Josh not John).  Note that I finally tracked down the link to the MQ v7.0 Knowledge center page "[CipherSuite and CipherSpec name mappings for connections to a WebSphere MQ queue manager](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.xms.doc/concepts/xms_csecure_mapping_wmq.html)".  This actually shows that even MQ 7.0 did not support SHA256 CipherSuites.  This being the case MQ v6.0 and MQ v5.3 would for sure not have supported them.  Looks like you will need to upgrade to a supported level of WAS.

Comment: The lack of SHA-2 support in MQ v7.0 is also supported by [APAR IV66840](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840) which states "The following WebSphere MQ CipherSuite to CipherSpec mappings
have been enabled by this APAR for WebSphere MQ v7.1 and v7.5
where the classes for Java and classes for JMS support SHA-2"  It references some non-SHA256 ciphersuites that were enabled for 7.0 then goes on to state the quoted text above.

Comment: Hi Josh..Thanks for the link. I went through the APAR IV66840, and it states that the solution was supposed to be provided in fix level 7.0.1.13 for MQv7.0. However the WMQ that I am using is already at 7.0.1.14 level currently. I guess this issue must have been fixed already? Please correct if I am wrong.I am struggling with this issue for last 1 week, and I'm just not able to get around it.Please advise.

Comment: Please see what I wrote above.  That APAR did not fix anything related to SHA-2 ciphersuite support in 7.0.0.13, it specifically states it only added a few non-SHA-2 ciphersuites.  I was providing that as second for of reference that 7.0 does not support SHA-2.  The first reference is the Knowledge center which does not  list a SHA-2 cipher.  Stating this again: You will need to upgrade to a supported level of WAS.

Comment: Apologies Josh! I totally got your point now! Actually I mixed up WMQ v7.0 and WMQ v7.1. That probably explains the issue and the need to upgrade from WMQ v7.0 to atleast v7.1 for SHA-2 to work. Thanks Josh! Thank you so much for this clue! Cheers!

Comment: V7.1 and V7.5 will work with Java 6.  You may be able to use the RA from one of those versions with your WAS 7.0 install.

Comment: Vikram did the above help?  I would like to capture this in a answer for you and future users if this seems to have been the resolution of your issue.

Comment: Hi Josh..I had tried with the 7.5 version jar, but that did not help. The MQ server is yet to be upgraded. They are not convinced. Instead, environment team is proposing to add custom properties in JVM to enable SSLv3. No one is interested in forward fix. Will update as soon as I am able to test your sggestions.

Comment: What version of MQ is the server running?  Also I was suggesting updating the WAS config to point to a RA from 7.5 not just including a 7.5 jar.  You should not include just a single jar like `com.ibm.mq.jar` when deploying to WAS since WAS already has the RA.  In this case my suggestion is to replace the RA that comes with WAS 7.0.0.43 (MQ RA 7.0.1.14) with a RA from MQ 7.5.

Comment: Here is a link that provides instructions on how to update the RA that comes with WAS to a version you download. https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/261379/can-i-upgrade-the-mq-ra-resource-adapter-which-is/?smartspace=messaging.  The next link is a download link for the MQ v7.5 RA: https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere+MQ&release=7.5&platform=All&function=textSearch&text=Resource+Adapter

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the WAS JVM cannot work with the cipher suite you use on the MQ channel. My guess is that it's complaining about the SHA-2 signature algorithm. You may need to use the unrestricted/unlimited export policy files. Check out the instructions at [IBM WAS manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_egs.html) and [IBM Java SDK Security Guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.71.doc/security-component/sdkpolicyfiles.html).

Comment: Hi..the cipher suite is SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 and the cipher spec is - TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256. I thought that the unrestricted/unlimited policy files were applicable in case of - SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256?

Comment: @VikramMullick My bad. I missed the key length. Actually, if you have the most recent JVM, you shouldn't need the unlimited export policy files (anymore) per https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170157 

Do you have anything in JRE's java.security and/or java.policy files that would cause the rejection of this cipher spec? 

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI54960

Comment: Hi Bora - Let me check these details in WAS servers from the server team, and come back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing, but also check what @JoshMc suggested. Old MQ JAR files might also be causing this.